Connection starts from the bottom
I am using schemabloc package to draw some block diagram. Consider this minimal codes:
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{schemabloc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \sbEntree{E}
    \sbBloc{A}{$A$}{E}
    \sbDecaleNoeudy[-4]{A}{u}
    \sbBloc[4]{B}{$B$}{u}
    \sbRelieryx{A}{B}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

It produces this output:

As we can see, the arrow starts from the bottom of block A. How to make it starts from the top of block A?

Without test, try A.north

@MS-SPO Can you elaborate a little?

That’s a standard anchor in Tikz, like in \draw (A.north)––(B);

(\draw[sbStyleLien] (A) |- (B); to get the same path and style as the \sbRelieryx)
